# De-Duplicate in Pandas based off of multiple rules

Tags: python, pandas

I want to de-dupe rows in pandas based off of multiple criteria.

I have 3 columns: name, id and nick_name.

First rule is look for duplicate id's. When id's match, only keep rows where name and nick_name are different as long as I am keeping at least one row.

In other words, if name and nick_name don't match, keep that row. If name and nick_name match, then get rid of that row, as long as it isn't the only row that would be left for that id.

Example data:

```
data = {"name": ["Sam", "Sam", "Joseph", "Joseph", "Joseph", "Philip", "Philip", "James"],
        "id": [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4],
        "nick_name": ["Sammie", "Sam", "Joseph", "Joe", "Joey", "Philip", "Philip", "James"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Produces:

```
    name    id  nick_name
0   Sam     1   Sammie
1   Sam     1   Sam
2   Joseph  2   Joseph
3   Joseph  2   Joe
4   Joseph  2   Joey
5   Philip  3   Philip
6   Philip  3   Philip
7   James   4   James
```

Based on my rules above, I want a resulting dataframe to produce the following:

```
    name    id  nick_name
0   Sam     1   Sammie
3   Joseph  2   Joe
4   Joseph  2   Joey
5   Philip  3   Philip
7   James   4   James
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split this into 3 boolean condtions to filter your initial dataframe by.

```
#where name and nick_name match, keep the first value.

con1 = df.duplicated(subset=['name','nick_name'],keep='first')

# where ids are duplicated and name is not equal to nick_name

con2 = df.duplicated(subset=['id'],keep=False) & df['name'].ne(df['nick_name'])

# where no duplicate exists. 

con3 = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('size').eq(1)

print(df.loc[con1 | con2 | con3])


 name  id nick_name
0     Sam   1    Sammie
3  Joseph   2       Joe
4  Joseph   2      Joey
6  Philip   3    Philip
7   James   4     James
```